# Error while setting up Detekt custom rules

Tags: android, static-analysis, detekt

I have setup Detekt in a multi module project. Below is my root level `build.gradle`

```
tasks.register("detektAll", Detekt) {
    description = "Custom Detekt build for all modules"
    parallel = true
    setSource(file(projectDir))
    config.setFrom(files("$rootDir/detekt.yml"))
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
    classpath.setFrom(project.configurations.getByName("detekt"))
    include("**/*.kt")
    exclude("**/build/**")
    reports {
        html {
            enabled = true
            destination = file("$rootDir/build/reports/detekt-results.html")
        }
        xml.enabled = false
        txt.enabled = false
    }
}
```

Now I am looking at setting up custom rule for which I followed [this](https://medium.com/@vanniktech/writing-your-first-detekt-rule-ee940e56428d)

This is what my `build.gradle` of `customdetekt` module looks like

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compileOnly "io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt:detekt-api:1.17.1"
    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.13.2"
    testImplementation "org.assertj:assertj-core:3.20.2"
    testImplementation "io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt:detekt-api:1.17.1"
    testImplementation "io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt:detekt-test:1.17.1"
}
```

Now when I hook up custom rule module in my main module using this:

```
detektPlugins project(path: ':customdetekt', configuration: 'default')
```

I get an error:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method detektPlugins() for arguments [DefaultProjectDependency{dependencyProject='project ':customdetekt''
```

Please help